# Resolving apparent logical flaw in methods for solving PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I'm reading Partial Differential Equations by Evans (available in pdf https://math24.files.wordpress.com/2013/02/partial-differential-equations-by-evans.pdf, which is one of several copies that come up when I google "PDE Evans"), and a lot of the arguments appear to go like this:

1. We are searching for a function $u$ that satisfies a particular PDE
2. We define some other function, say $w$, in terms of $u$
3. We show that if a specific $u$ solves the first PDE, a specific $w$ will satisfy the second
4. We derive a $w$ that satisfies the second
5. We conclude the corresponding $u$ satisfies the first.

An example of this occurs on pg 194 (pg 202 of the linked pdf) of the first edition, on the "Cole-Hopf transformation", but arguments of this shape (modulo my likely confusion) appear throughout the book.

My confusion is, this appears to be a logical fallacy of the form "If A then B, therefore B then A". That is, it feels like we're taking "if u satisfies then w will" and assuming that this means "if w satisfies then u will".

One idea I had is that, maybe we aren't saying this itself the proof, but rather this is helping us find a good *candidate* for u, then, if it just so happens it satisfies the original PDE then we've solved it, and the author isn't showing us the tedious checking portion?

(Meta point: my apologies for not reproducing an example of such an actual argument here, if there are suggestions for handling such external material I'm happy to look into them.)

Comment: Yes, your thinking is correct - the process produces a candidate for $u$ but doesn't ensure its correctness. However, if we are given that (1) there *exists* a solution to the original equation, (2) $\phi$ is bijective, and (3) $w$ is unique, then the argument holds. Proof: Let $u$ be a solution of the original equation (which exists). Then $\phi (u)$ solves the second equation. By uniqueness, $w = \phi (u)$, and since $\phi$ is bijective, $u = \phi^{-1} (w)$.